# What does option-up and option-down do in TextMate?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

If you press alt-up and alt-down in the cursor jumps vertically through the document while staying within a column. Its movement seem unpredictable but I'm sure there's a use for it. Anyone know what it's for?

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> and <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>, then the movement is probably to the beginning and end of paragraph.  That is the standard [Mac OS X key binding](http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/Site/System%20Bindings.html).  I'm not sure how TextMate defines paragraphs, but that would be my guess.

Comment: When I was using TextMate I kind of assumed it jumped to the next "similar" line but, as they were a bit mysterious and unpredictable I didn't really use these shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

It is ["column movement."](http://manual.macromates.com/en/working_with_text#column_movement_typing)  In some contexts it doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but when you have columns of data it works quite nicely to jump to the top and bottom of the column.

Use it with <kbd>shift</kbd> to make a columnar selection, allowing you to easily write the same thing to every line.